# How to perform multiple insertion using django rest viewsets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm working on this api where a user can select multiple languages and can mark the proficiency in each language. The model is as follows.

```
class UserLanguage(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  proficiency = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

  class Meta:
      db_table = "user_language"
```

Serializer looks like:

```
class UserLanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = UserLanguage
      fields = '__all__'
```

I have done the views as follows

```
class UserLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = UserLanguage.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserLanguageSerializer
```

The code works fine for a request like

```
{
    "proficiency": "04.00",
    "user": 1,
    "language": 1
}
```

I want the api to accept a list like this:

```
[
{
    "proficiency": "05.00",
    "user": 1,
    "language": 1
},
{
    "proficiency": "04.00",
    "user": 1,
    "language": 1
}]
```

For each item in the list I want to create a new row in 'user_language' table.

Am I doing it the right way? If not show me the right way.

How should I modify my models, serializer or view to attain this?

I don't know if the above request is in the right format. If not please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to override the create method so the serializer accepts many=True.

```
class UserLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserLanguage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserLanguageSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = UserLanguageSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid:
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: The above code is working. Thanks @Guillaume. The code is creating multiple values i.e for the user it creates multiple values for the same data. How can I make it unique with fields 'user' and 'language'.  eg: [
    {
        "proficiency": "04.00",
        "user": 1,
        "language": 1
    },
    {
        "proficiency": "04.00",
        "user": 1,
        "language": 1
    }
]
  The  value of 'user' and 'language' in both item is same and creates two rows. But I want to create only single row in table. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @AryanVR You need to ensure that in your model. Take a look at that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together